# Waiting until callback function is executed

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I have a JavaScript class where pass `options` object in init function.
this `options` object also contains a `callback` function

this `callback function` is a globally defined function which create `Ajax Request` and updates the contents.

After the contents are updated, I want to register some event on the controls returned by the Ajax

Is there a way that the Class method (which calls the callback function) waits util the contains are updated and then registers the events?

Comment: could you show some code please?

Comment: you'd probably have to pass a callback to the callback

Comment: The callback method could trigger an event handler, maybe.

Comment: @Nile please your comments as answer. I would like to accept your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you have to pass another callback the first callback. Something like:

```
var feedDog = function(callback){
    fedDog = true; //feed the dog

    callback(function(){
        alert("This will alert as a callback to feedDog's callback.");
    });
};

feedDog(function(callback){
    alert("Fed dog");
    callback();
});
```